# Printing in angular running on electron closes main process

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I'm trying to print `<div>` in angular-electron application, when I click on print (sometimes when I close the new window) it also closes the main process. I'm not able log, to check whats causing this issue.

main.ts

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: size.width,
    height: size.height,
    webPreferences: {
        nativeWindowOpen: true, // set as true
        nodeIntegration: true,
        allowRunningInsecureContent: (serve) ? true : false,
        enableRemoteModule: true
    },
});
...
app.on('window-all-closed', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // added this line
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});
```

details.component.ts

```
printFees() {
    var prtContent = document.getElementById('print-section');
    var WinPrint = window.open('', '_blank', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
    WinPrint.document.open();
    WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
    WinPrint.setTimeout(function () {
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
        WinPrint.close();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Have you resolved it?

Comment: No, this is the bug in the electron, you can check issue here. https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/25397

Comment: As temporary solution I'm using [PDFKit](https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit)